# 2-order difference equation as a system of 1-order difference equations

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems

I've been given the relation:

(1) $Y(t)=C(t)+I(t)+G(t)$

I've been given these asumptions 1 to describe (1):

(2a) $C(t)=bY(t-1)$

(2b) $I(t)=k(C(t)-C(t-1)$

(2c) $G(t)=G_0$

$k>0$ and $0<b<1$

Although (2c) isn't a difference equation it is my initial value, making the 2 order difference equation inhomogenous:

(3) $Y(t)=(bk+b)Y(t-1)-kbY(t-2)+G(0)$

My question is, how do i describe (3) as a system of 1 order difference equations?

I am to represent it as a vector system:

(4) $\begin{bmatrix}
Y_1(t+1)\\
Y_2(t+2)
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
&&&\\
&&&
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
Y_1(t)\\
Y_2(t)
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
G(0)
\end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define $Y_2(t)=Y(t), Y_1(t)=Y(t-1)$.  The point is to make it only one time step, so you rewrite $(3)$ as
$Y_1(t)=(bk+b)Y_1(t-1)-kbY_2(t-1)+G(0)$

Your matrix equation should be 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
Y_1(t+1)\\
Y_2(t+1)
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
&&&\\
&&&
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
Y_1(t)\\
Y_2(t)
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
G(0)\\0
\end{bmatrix}$$
Your empty box will be a $2 \times 2$ matrix that reflects the new version of $(3)$, so 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
Y_1(t+1)\\
Y_2(t+1)
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
bk+b&-kb\\
1&0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
Y_1(t)\\
Y_2(t)
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
G(0)\\0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: I wonder, shouldn't the matrix be:
$\begin{bmatrix}
bk+b & -kb\\
1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: You are right.  Fixed.

Comment: Thank you, it was just what i needed.